# Jupyter loading blank web page

Tags: python, port, jupyter

Following a system crash, jupyter has stopped working on port 8888.

The menu navigation works fine, but creating a new notebook or loading the one I was working on before my computer crashed results in a blank web-page.

I am using Chrome, running on Mac OS X.

I have attempted browser history and cache clearing (as recomended in the answers to similar questions), rebooting and reinstalling jupyter. The last one just seemed to give me more errors appearing in the console (or at least I don't remember seeing the last two, but can't double check).

As it still worked on port 8889, I just carried on using it. However 8889 has just started failing in the same way - and I'm now using port 8890. Calling 'netstat -anp tcp' in the terminal doesn't show anything running on ports 8888 or 8889.

The following is the current output from the console, taken from trying to run it on port 8888:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'h' of undefined
    at index.js?v=f865e990e65ad27e3a2601d8adb48db1:1
    at index.js?v=f865e990e65ad27e3a2601d8adb48db1:1
    at index.js?v=f865e990e65ad27e3a2601d8adb48db1:1
(anonymous) @ index.js?v=f865e990e65ad27e3a2601d8adb48db1:1
(anonymous) @ index.js?v=f865e990e65ad27e3a2601d8adb48db1:1
(anonymous) @ index.js?v=f865e990e65ad27e3a2601d8adb48db1:1

ReferenceError: preact is not defined
    at commandpalette.js:118
    at Object.execCb (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1690)
    at Module.check (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:865)
    at Module.enable (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1177)
    at Object.enable (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1550)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1162)
    at require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:131
    at each (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:56)
    at Module.enable (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1114)
    at Object.enable (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1550)
check @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:900
enable @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1177
enable @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:131
each @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:56
enable @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1114
enable @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1550
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1162
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:131
each @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:56
enable @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1114
init @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:783
(anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1453
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1809
localRequire @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1442
requirejs @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1791
(anonymous) @ clipboard.js:80
require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:900 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ShortcutEditor' of undefined
        at shortcuteditor.js:198
        at Object.execCb (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1690)
        at Module.check (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:865)
        at Module.enable (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1177)
        at Object.enable (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1550)
        at Module.<anonymous> (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1162)
        at require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:131
        at each (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:56)
        at Module.enable (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1114)
        at Module.init (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:783)
    check @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:900
    enable @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1177
    enable @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1550
    (anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1162
    (anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:131
    each @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:56
    enable @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1114
    init @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:783
    (anonymous) @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1453
    setTimeout (async)
    req.nextTick @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1809
    localRequire @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1442
    requirejs @ require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1791
    (anonymous) @ clipboard.js:80
    require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:900 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Notebook' of undefined
            at main.js:24
            at Object.execCb (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1690)
            at Module.check (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:865)
            at Module.<anonymous> (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1140)
            at require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:131
            at require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1190
            at each (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:56)
            at Module.emit (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1189)
            at Module.check (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:940)
            at Module.enable (require.js?v=6da8be361b9ee26c5e721e76c6d4afce:1177)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Faced the same problem (12.03.2019) 
(Maybe) The first solution: clean browser cache. Sometimes it solves the problem.

If success == false

try to downgrade notebook to 5.7.4 (or 5.7.5)

```
pip uninstall notebook
pip install notebook==5.7.4 (or 5.7.5)
```

It helped me

GitHub [link on the issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467)

Comment: But it seems it's not a good solution. Works with Chrome. Opera has the same blank page. Using Vs Code with jupyter notebook 5.7.4 no gives results. I'm confused.  Maybe  I made mistake elsewhere. Also Chrome is not showing the output of any code executed on the cell. Try my lack with anaconda.

Comment: Working with Anaconda Navigator right now. (Python 3.6.8 or Python 3.7 ) and (Jupyter Notebook 5.7.4 or Jupyter Notebook 5.7.6) also gives blank page. I think I'm stupid. Tried to use JupyterLab. JupyterLab's notebook is working!

Comment: Downgrading the notebook version worked for me, thanks.  Was struggling with getting the conda environment to show up as a kernel option, so installed nb_conda_kernels which upgraded the notebook version to version 5.7.6.  Had to downgrade to 5.7.5 for it to work again.
Edit:  Just wanted to add that I tried cleaning the browser cache, only downgrading the version worked. 5.7.5 and 5.7.4 worked fine.