# Jupyter notebook webpage is a blank screen

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, mime-types, miniconda

So I bought this fancy shmancy Codecademy Pro subscription to take the data science track, but it appears that it has a rather disappointing lack of documentation for part six of its course. I'm learning about Python right now, and I just downloaded the newest version of Miniconda, which included Python 3.7.2. I'm trying to open a .zip file (called Reggie's Linear Regression.zip) using the command

```
jupyter notebook
```

and it works, to some extent; it automatically launches a Chrome page, but it's just blank. I get this error in the Chrome console:

```
Refused to execute script from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I want it to show this file: Reggie_Linear_Regression_Skeleton.ipynb. It just opens in my notes app when I click on it in file explorer.

I'm *very* new to Python and downloading libraries and stuff (this is actually my first time), so even just pointing me to other resources that would help me with this problem would be helpful as I don't even know how to describe the issue. Also, I'm 100% sure I've navigated to the correct folder in the Anaconda prompt.

Thanks so much

Comment: Related: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter loading blank web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53318132/jupyter-loading-blank-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

The latest version seems to be broken, try to downgrade jupyter.  If you install with Anaconda the command is:

```
conda install -c anaconda notebook=5.7.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, looks like the latest version is broken. There is already a pull request but it is not yet merged https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4468. That is a pretty simple fix, so you can also do it yourself for the time being https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/4468/files

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

Downgrade jupyter notebook. If you face the blank page againg, after opening jupyter notebook on broswer press "ctrl+f5" to force restart the page.